xamarin: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#crc64df999be563077fc4.BootReceiver>
Brief Introduction:
We have xamarin app deployed through enterprise mobile management and when installing the app the Google Play Protect displays this:

So in effort for this pop-up not to display, I updated the target framework version of our xamarin app to Android API Level 34.
This is the error that I get:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#crc64df999be563077fc4.BootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
Even when I add the android:exported like in this code snippet:
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="crc64df999be563077fc4.BootReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

UPDATE: I don't encounter the error below anymore after I updated the Xamarin.Work.Runtime package version to v2.7.0. But the android:exported issue still remains
It would clear the android:export after rebuilding the app, and the error would still remain. Occasionally when just building it directly after adding the android:export, it would run but it would hit it with this error and crash:
**Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:** 'com.alsco.mobile: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.'

I also did remove a zebra sdk that is already deprecated, and also updated the dependencies to their latest monoandroid12, but it didn't help much.
Any help would be very much appreciated.
PS: We already have .NET MAUI project for this but it's still in testing phase. So we still have to maintain the current xamarin app in production.
